# custom ListView command set extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, listviewcommandset

I am very new to SPFX and would like to know if you can help me. I have added a new option to the context menu; please see the photo below.

What I need is for when the users click on either of the new menus, it takes them to, for instance, `https://google.com` or another path.

Can you please let me know where in the code I can achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your business logic in `onExecute` method.

For example:

```
@override
public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
  switch (event.itemId) {
    case 'COMMAND_1':
      window.open('https://google.com','_blank');
      break;
    case 'COMMAND_2':
      window.open('https://google.com','_blank');
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error('Unknown command');
  }
}
```

**Documentation**: [Build your first ListView Command Set extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)